# Text overflows into graphics at bottom of page

Tags: graphics, lengths

I want to include graphics on every page after the title page but on the 2nd page the text flows into the graphics and I also loose the page number on that page. Subsequent pages are fine.

Here is my MWW:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{eso-pic}
    \usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example
    \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

    \title{Doc Title}

    \begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \makeatletter
    \newpage

    \addtolength{\textheight}{-68mm}
    \addtolength{\footskip}{68mm}

    \AddToShipoutPicture{
        \setlength{\@tempdimb}{.5\paperwidth}
        \setlength{\@tempdimc}{.21\paperheight}
        \setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}
        \put(\strip@pt\@tempdimb,\strip@pt\@tempdimc){
            \makebox(0,0) {
                \setlength{\fboxsep}{2mm}
                \fbox{
                   \includegraphics{Some-logo.jpg}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    \clearpage
    \begin{center}
    {\huge\sc chapter one}
    \vspace{8mm}
    \end{center} 
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \lipsum
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Changing `\textheight` after `\begin{document}` has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you shouldn't adjust `\textheight` by yourself and instead let the geometry package take care of that. That's what it is for. So remove

```
\addtolength{\textheight}{-68mm}
```

and set it with geometry

```
\usepackage[margin=2cm, bottom=88mm]{geometry}
```

---

EDIT: Here is a complete example with `\newgeometry`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\title{Doc Title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\newpage

\makeatletter
\AddToShipoutPicture{
    \setlength{\@tempdimb}{.5\paperwidth}
    \setlength{\@tempdimc}{.21\paperheight}
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}
    \put(\strip@pt\@tempdimb,\strip@pt\@tempdimc){
        \makebox(0,0) {
            \setlength{\fboxsep}{2mm}
            \fbox{
               \includegraphics{Some-logo.jpg}
            }
        }
    }
}
\makeatother
\newgeometry{bottom=88mm,footskip=\dimexpr\footskip+68mm\relax}

\begin{center}
{\huge\sc chapter one}
\vspace{8mm}
\end{center} 

\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\clearpage
\ClearShipoutPicture{}
\restoregeometry
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Setting it with geometry causes the page numbering on the title page to be moved up. I only want the text height to be changed on specific pages.

Comment: Then use `\newgeometry{bottom=88mm}` of the geometry package after the title page. And if you need to reset it use `\restoregeometry`.